# Assigning strlen(s) value to an integer is varying the output, WHY?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, character, strlen

```
char s[100];
cin>>s;
int x=strlen(s);
if((x-2)>=9)
cout<<s[0]<<x-2<<s[x-1]<<endl;    
else
cout<<s<<endl;
```

output for inputting 'a' is 'a' BUT

```
char s[100];
cin>>s;
if((strlen(s)-2)>=9)
cout<<s[0]<<strlen(s)-2<<s[strlen(s)-1]<<endl;    
else
cout<<s<<endl;
```

OUTPUT of this program for same input 'a' is a18446744073709551615a.

Just assigning strlen(s) value to an integer is avoiding the problem to happen. WHY ??

From where is that garbage value of 18446744073709551615a coming from, and if the "if" condition is being compiled in second case then also , why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen) returns `size_t` - an **unsigned** type.

According to [integral conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) rules, the type of `strlen(s)-2` remains unsigned, which overflows for any `strlen(s)` less than 2, wrapping around and giving a large positive value (2<sup>64</sup>-1 in your example).

When you first assign `strlen(s)` to an `int` variable, the value is converted to type `int` and the result of `1-2` becomes `-1`. You can achieve the same by casting `strlen(s)` to `int`:

```
  if ((static_cast<int>(strlen(s))) - 2) >= 9) ...
```

Or just move `-2` to the other side of the comparison:

```
  if (strlen(s) >= 9 + 2) ...
```

Answer (score 7):

When you input `a`, `strlen` will return *unsigned* (`size_t`) `1`. `1 - 2` will not be `-1` but wrap around at 0 and give you a *very* large unsigned integer (18446744073709551615 in your case).